# ZF2 - How to re-direct to External URL

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 and I am wondering how to re-direct to an external URL.

This is what I have tried:

```
    $this->redirect()->toUrl('http://www.example.com' ,
        [
            'access_code'         => '12345'
        ]
    );
```

Unfortunately it does not work.

The other thought was to simple use something like:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/12345');
```

EDIT:

This is being done from my controller, here is the controller code:

```
use Application\Library\Http\GetHttpInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
class GamesController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function __construct(
        //factories
    ) {
        //objects
    }

    public function redirectAction()
    {

        $this->redirect()->toUrl("http://www.example.com");


       echo "here";

    }

}
```

Comment: You want to redirect from your controller ?

Comment: That was the idea (unless it should be done from the view, I have never had to do this before).

Comment: Try this : `return $this->redirect()->toUrl('http://www.example.com/12345');`

Comment: Ahh thanks If you add this as an answer I will accept it! I had left out the "return" part!! Shew long day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just missed the `return` in your instruction. It should be like this:

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl('http://www.example.com/12345');
```